# Android Currency Display: Device vs. Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, currency

In my program, I have a section that displays the various currencies using the java NumberFormat.  As an example, the following three lines will give you the currency format for Algeria.

```
chosenlocale = new Locale("ar","DZ");

NumberFormat currencyformatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(chosenlocale);

String currencyexample = currencyformatter.format(Double.parseDouble("0000.00000"));
```

When I run this in the Android emulator, I get the cool and funky characters, but I do not when I run it on my device.  I assume that if the device was native to Algeria, the characters would display as they do in the emulator.  Is my assumption a good one?

Many thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption would be correct.

On your android device you can set an option that will let you use Simulated Locales (Definitions -> Applications -> Development) and you can even define another location for you device (Definitions -> Region and Text -> Select Region)

In your app you can also set a locale for the device (that won't change the system configuration)

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Take a look at setLocale(Locale locale)